# Node Js Directory Error when working with multiple directories - ENOENT

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I have a couple of directories. They interact with each other and require each other in some cases. In my example functions.js inside of Handler has this;

```
let ReadDatabase = fs.readFileSync('../Database/database.json');
```

when I run functions to try out some functions it works this way.

but when I run index.js I got this error;

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\Cheek\Desktop\Database\database.json'

When I change the directory to this in functions;

```
let ReadDatabase = fs.readFileSync('./Database/database.json');
```

the index.js works but I got a similar error when I run functions.js

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\Cheek\Desktop\SBM_Bot\Handlers\Database\database.json'

[image: Directories]

What am I doing wrong here? I am going to use that functions.js on other files as well, how can I make it in a way that it will work for every file even if I deploy from another machine?

Answer (score 1):

My Advice is you could use (NCONF) https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf is the better way to read json file for configuration purpose, use this command: NPM INSTALL NCONF --SAVE to install it to your package files. anything else let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll look into it. For this project I think I need this, but if I understand and learn and if its easy, I'll just implement this